# Serialization issue: Object keys <> being stripped by php cURL

Tags: php, curl

I have a web service that I am working with and using PHP/cURL to connect with. When I use postman I get

```
"ShippingInfo": {
    "<ShippingMethodId>k__BackingField": 0,
    "<ShippingMethod>k__BackingField": null,
    "<ShippingNote>k__BackingField": null,
    "<ShippingProvider>k__BackingField": null
},
```

which is correct but when I dump the values in my Drupal site, I get

```
"ShippingInfo":{"k__BackingField":0,"k__BackingField":null,"k__BackingField":null,"k__BackingField":null}
```

It seems to be trimming off the <Shipping*> from the response. Any ideas on why this might be happening and how to make it stop?

**Here is my cURL call:**

```
ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'tokenvalidate: ' . $this->TOKEN;
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/json; charset=UTF-8';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    watchdog('cURL error', curl_errno($ch));
} else {
    return $result;
}
curl_close($ch);
```

This seems to be the only object that is having the issue. All other calls are fine.

Comment: Because you didn't escape output?

Comment: Are you sure that is missing? How are you inspecting the 'dumped values'? Raw source in browser devtools, or just looking at it in a rendered browser window?

Comment: @IncredibleHat I am using Drupal 7 so I am using watchdog to print the json string

Comment: @u_mulder Please explain escaping the output

Comment: Right but, how are you, personally, viewing this output from php? See, if you view a string in just a browser window, that has `<` and `>`, your browser is going to hide those as it considers them some form of html tag. However if you view the raw source in your browsers devtools... it will not hide anything with tags and the like.

Comment: similarly, who knows what `watchdog` does ... you are observing its output no ?

Comment: @IncredibleHat - You, my friend, are brilliant. I dumped the result to a file and it's there.. Post that as an answer and I can mark it correct! Thank you very much!

Comment: But... its not really an answer. Its simply an observation point. Your code 'works', there was nothing wrong to solve. :D

Comment: And there is definitely a duplicate as I see one every couple of days.

Comment: The basic point is that displaying text in a web page doesn't let you see the raw contents, it's being rendered as HTML. Lines are wrapped, HTML tags are processed, etc.